# Can someone post a well formed crossdomain.xml sample?

Tags: flash, crossdomain.xml

I've been reading that Adobe has made crossdomain.xml stricter in flash 9-10 and I'm wondering of someone can paste me a copy of one that they know works. Having some trouble finding a recent sample on Adobe's site.

Comment: This might seem dangerously obvious, but as a Flash developer with 10 years experience, I can tell you that every policy file I've ever implemented has failed at not even pretended to work... until today. Turns out you need to ACTUALLY LOAD the policy file yourself. The docs make it sound like Flash will automatically go looking for crossdomain.xml files by itself prior to having a SecuritySandbox error. So if you're struggling, make sure you ARE LOADING the policy file: Security.loadPolicyFile("http://www.example.com/crossdomain.xml")

Answer (score 103, accepted):

This is what I've been using for development:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<cross-domain-policy>
<allow-access-from domain="*" />
</cross-domain-policy>
```

This is a very liberal approach, but is fine for my application.

**As others have pointed out below, beware the risks of this.**

Comment: This works in a sense, but please note the risks: this means that *any* website can send requests to your website on the user's behalf, cookies and all, and read the response without issue. For most web apps, this is a huge security vulnerability. So, while this approach has its place, please know the risks and take a strict whitelist approach when necessary (which is almost always for production apps).

Comment: Do **not** use this outside development. This exactly matches the example of a "badly configured crossdomain.xml" from the [hardened PHP project](http://www.hardened-php.net/library/poking_new_holes_with_flash_crossdomain_policy_files.html#badly_configured_crossdomain.xml).

Comment: if you're serving the file yourself, remember to set the correct contentType: "text/x-cross-domain-policy"

Comment: There is one (and only one) circumstance where this would be acceptable in a production environment: where you are installing it on a domain that *only* serves static files for the use of applications on other domains.  Example: you have an "images.mydomain.com" subdomain that serves all of your site's images (presumably using some kind of CDN) and *nothing else*.

Answer (score 34):

If you're using webservices, you'll also need the 'allow-http-request-headers-from' element. Here's our default, development, 'allow everything' policy.

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<cross-domain-policy>
  <site-control permitted-cross-domain-policies="master-only"/>
  <allow-access-from domain="*"/>
  <allow-http-request-headers-from domain="*" headers="*"/>
</cross-domain-policy>
```

Comment: perhaps you should mention if / how this could be dangerous?

Comment: Where to save this XML file

Comment: I always use Adobe's scheme. Here is an example of a loose one: [http://stackoverflow.com/a/26433744/257319](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26433744/257319)

Comment: Save on the domain level that you wish it to affect. eg. http://www.example.com/crossdomain.xml

Answer (score 30):

Take a look at Twitter's:

http://twitter.com/crossdomain.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<cross-domain-policy xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="http://www.adobe.com/xml/schemas/PolicyFile.xsd">
    <allow-access-from domain="twitter.com" />
    <allow-access-from domain="api.twitter.com" />
    <allow-access-from domain="search.twitter.com" />
    <allow-access-from domain="static.twitter.com" />
    <site-control permitted-cross-domain-policies="master-only"/>
    <allow-http-request-headers-from domain="*.twitter.com" headers="*" secure="true"/>
</cross-domain-policy>
```

Comment: or https://www.adobe.com/crossdomain.xml
or https://github.com/crossdomain.xml
or https://twitter.com/crossdomain.xml
or https://www.facebook.com/crossdomain.xml
or https://www.google.com/crossdomain.xml
or https://www.bing.com/crossdomain.xml
or https://medium.com/crossdomain.xml or https://developers.google.com/crossdomain.xml

Answer (score 9):

In production site this seems suitable:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<cross-domain-policy>
<allow-access-from domain="www.mysite.com" />
<allow-access-from domain="mysite.com" />
</cross-domain-policy>
```

Answer (score 6):

A version of **crossdomain.xml** used to be packaged with the [HTML5 Boilerplate](https://html5boilerplate.com/) which is *the product of many years of iterative development and combined community knowledge.* However, it has since been deleted from the repository. I've copied it verbatim here, and included a link to the commit where it was deleted below.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE cross-domain-policy SYSTEM "http://www.adobe.com/xml/dtds/cross-domain-policy.dtd">
<cross-domain-policy>
  <!-- Read this: https://www.adobe.com/devnet/articles/crossdomain_policy_file_spec.html -->

  <!-- Most restrictive policy: -->
  <site-control permitted-cross-domain-policies="none"/>

  <!-- Least restrictive policy: -->
  <!--
  <site-control permitted-cross-domain-policies="all"/>
  <allow-access-from domain="*" to-ports="*" secure="false"/>
  <allow-http-request-headers-from domain="*" headers="*" secure="false"/>
  -->
</cross-domain-policy>
```

Deleted in #1881
https://github.com/h5bp/html5-boilerplate/commit/58a2ba81d250301e7b5e3da28ae4c1b42d91b2c2