# error trying to utilize a crossdomain.xml file with a sharepoint server

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, sharepoint, crossdomain.xml

I'm trying to get a .swf file stored on a website to access files stored on my SharePoint server and I am having trouble getting the crossdomain.xml file on the SharePoint server to work properly.  I am somewhat confused on where to place the file.  At the moment it is located in the folder containing the relevant files.  That folder is in one of the subdomains of the main site.  I'm not sure that that's correct.

Comment: Can you please post the contents of the crossdomain.xml?

Comment: <?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE cross-domain-policy SYSTEM "http://www.adobe.com/sml/dtds/cross-domain-policy.dtd">

<cross-domain-policy>
 <site-control permitted-cross-domain-policies="master-only"/>
 <allow-access-from domain="http://www.vmsimplex.com/jobsfeed.html"/>
</cross-domain-policy>

Comment: <?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE cross-domain-policy SYSTEM "http://www.adobe.com/sml/dtds/cross-domain-policy.dtd">

<cross-domain-policy>
 <site-control permitted-cross-domain-policies="master-only"/>
 <allow-access-from domain="http://www.vmsimplex.com/jobsfeed.html"/>
</cross-domain-policy>

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your xml has some issues. You don't need those semicolons. Also, if you just want to allow cross domain access to your entire site you can use a wildcard instead of the domain, which i think also has some issues. Check out this previous "stack overflow" question and try using their crossdomain snippet.

[Can someone post a well formed crossdomain.xml sample?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/213251/can-someone-post-a-well-formed-crossdomain-xml-sample)