# Flash and multiple domain / sub domains => crossdomain.xml?

Tags: flash, apache-flex, cross-domain, crossdomain.xml

I am trying to use a flash script (plupload) on all my domains and sub-domains hosting it on my static sub-domain.

The swf file is placed on my 
static.mydomain.com/path/to/file.swf

And I want to use this file on my others domains and subdomain like :
www.mydomain.com
or asubdomain.mydomain.com
I also would like to use it on another domain extension for the same domain name, like : 
mydomain.net

But I fail to use it. 
And if I put the swf file on my subdomain where I want to use it, it works fine.

So I think i need to place a crossdomain.xml somewhere but I don't no where ?
Only on my static subdomain ?
On each of my subdomains ?

Thanks for the help

Comment: I'm very unclear what you're asking.  What does "put the swf file on my subdomain" mean?  It sounds like you already put it on a subdomain ( static.mydomain.com ).  How are you attempting to use it on another domain?  What does "use it mean"?  I do not believe you can serve a file on one domain from another domain; unless you are somehow using virtual directories on the server or have both domains pointing to the same web root.  That would have nothing to do w/ cross domain files, though.

Comment: puttin the file on my subdomains meens that I can acces the file with my subdomain url :
if i want to use the swf file on asubdomain.mydomain.com
I can acces my swf on asubdomain.mydomain.com/path/to/file.swf with no problem.
But I have security problem when I try to access it on static.mydomain/path/to/file.swf

Comment: I think I'm only half understanding.  If you want a SWF on asubdomain.mydomain.com to access static.mydomain.com then you'll need a crossdomain file at static.mydomain.com/crossdomain.xml .  Or you could just serve the swf off static.mydomain.com and embed it anywhere you want (kind of like YouTube does w/ the share link of their player)

Comment: The second one : "Or you could just serve the swf off static.mydomain.com and embed it anywhere you want (kind of like YouTube does w/ the share link of their player)"
But it seems to not work. The script is : http://www.plupload.com/

Comment: I have used that embed approach without problems.  I don't know anything about that script so do not know what variables it may introduce to the usage of a "Remote embed"

Comment: So, embeding a swf from another domain do no need a crossdomain.xml file ?
i just foud this on their forum : http://www.plupload.com/punbb/viewtopic.php?id=1685

Comment: A SWF does not need a crossdomain.xml file in order to access services on the domain it was served off of.

Answer (score 3):

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE cross-domain-policy SYSTEM "http://www.adobe.com/xml/dtds/cross-domain-policy.dtd">
<cross-domain-policy>
  <site-control permitted-cross-domain-policies="all"/>
  <allow-access-from domain="*" secure="false"/>
  <allow-http-request-headers-from domain="*" headers="*" secure="false"/>
</cross-domain-policy>
```

if you want a 'less-loose' XML, duplicate either one of the `*` lines, putting your sub-domain(s) one by one, or using a shorthand such as `*.mydomain.com`.

taken from:

- [Adobe Crossdomain XML Policy Explained  <sub><sup>( www.adobe.com/devnet-docs/acrobatetk/tools/AppSec/xdomain.html )</sup></sub>](http://www.adobe.com/devnet-docs/acrobatetk/tools/AppSec/xdomain.html)
- [Example Above Taken From Here  <sub><sup>( icompile.eladkarako.com/loose-cross-domain-xml-policy )</sup></sub>](http://icompile.eladkarako.com/loose-cross-domain-xml-policy/)

.