# How to call external rest service from angularjs?

Tags: http, rest, angularjs

I am trying to call an external REST service from angular using $http service.
The thing is that I am stuck on the $http.get method, because everytime I call
 the rest service i get an error with status = 0 and no information in the data parameter 
 of the error callback.
So far I've tried calling a local service runnig on port 5000 : `$http.get('http://localhost:5000/ping')` and this is supposed to return a json object with a property and a value. Another approach was calling http://api.flickr.com/services/rest/?method=flickr.test.echo&name=test in the hope of getting an answer. For both of them I get the same error: that I mentioned earlier.
The call is made from an angular controller that has injected the http service.
Thanks.

Comment: There should not have spaces betweeen in your url.

Comment: To handle the response from and $http request: $http.get(url, {}).then(function(result) { console.log('success', result.data);}, function(result) { console.log('error'); });

Comment: Show us the code. How do you know that you get an error with status = 0 and no information in the data parameter
of the error callback. Even though this fails : http://api.flickr.com/services/rest/?method=flickr.test.echo&name=test as I have not provided an API key the status is 200 OK on my machine.

Comment: @jpmorin - i added the spaces by mistake while writing the question, url is fine.

Comment: @Basarat Ali I don't have access to the code right now, but the information that I posted is retrieved from firebug's javascript debugging tool.

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried:

```
    $http({method: 'GET', url: 'someURL'}).
            success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                //set view model or do something.

            }).
            error(function(data, status, headers, config) {

            });
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you have passed the parameters correctly if there are any.
The general syntax should be like the following :

```
$http.get('../link/yourApplication/searchBySomeNumber?someNum='+$scope.someNum+'&asOfDate='+asOfDate+'&status=undefined') 
            .success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                //your code
                console.log('Data return successful');
            })
            .error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                $scope.status = status;
                alert('Info Error');
                console.log('Group Info Error');
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

As $http returns a Promise, you can use the `.then()` method to log your results when the promise is resolved, or log an error in case anything goes wrong:

```
$http.get('http://localhost:5000/ping')
    .then(function(returnedJson) {
        console.log(returnedJson.data);
    })
    .catch(console.error) // or $log.error if you are using $log from Angular
```

Please note that the clean JSON response is obtained by logging the `.data` property of the `returnedJson` object. As it is a Promise, it contains other information that are not relevant to consume the web service.

Also note that the web service you want to consume should also be in the same domain as your Angular app, otherwise you may incur into a Cross Domain error, unless the service allows usage from external websites by exposing a Cross Domain Policy.

(Find more info here: [Can someone post a well formed crossdomain.xml sample?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/213251/can-someone-post-a-well-formed-crossdomain-xml-sample))

If that's the case, this post should be helpful:

[jQuery AJAX cross domain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3506208/jquery-ajax-cross-domain)

Hope this helps.