# Javascript Ajax Call always returns readyState=1 and status=0

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I am sending post request through AJAX as below.

I am always getting `xmlhttp.readyState = 1` and  `xmlhttp.status= 0` . **xmlhttp.responseText** is always **empty**.

Could you please tell me what could be the problem ?

> I expect xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200

```
<script>
//Ajax to send request..
function sendPayment()
{
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
      {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
      xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
      }
    else
      {// code for IE6, IE5
      xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
      }
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
          {
alert(xmlhttp.readyState);// this always returns = 1
alert(xmlhttp.responseText) ; //this is always empty.
          if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
            {
                if (xmlhttp.responseText=='1')
                {
                    alert('success');
                }   
            }
          }
    xmlhttp.open("POST","payments/callSSL.php",true);
    xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    xmlhttp.send(Id=100);
    return false;
}
</script>
```

**HTML PART**

```
<input name="button" type="submit" id="button" value="Confirm" onclick="sendPayment()" />
```

Comment: And does the `success` alert never show ?

Comment: xmlhttp.readyState always return true having ajax always return a value. please specify your status of ajax result

Comment: @adeneo : yes. I get only empty though i send some outputs in `/callSSL.php` file

Comment: check your callSSL.php , you have to echo not return your result

Comment: @rajeshkakawat : i just added `echo "1"` in the first line of callSSL.php file. still no use. same result..

Comment: call your callSSL.php directly from browser address bar see what you get?????

Comment: @rajeshkakawat : callSSL.php is my another site. i am calling from one site to another site. I just updated my question `http://my-other-site.com/payments/callSSL.php` - sorry for the miss

Comment: you can't call from another domain check this out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23053349/getting-cross-origin-block-request-cors-error-when-using-getjson-to-get-play

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/57594/discussion-between-logan-and-rajesh-kakawat).

Comment: @rajeshkakawat : I just moved my callSSL to same domain but still same issue. i think something else is issue

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/57595/discussion-between-rajesh-kakawat-and-logan).

Answer (score 1):

If you are calling to your own another site,you have to give permission in your another site  ie(http://my-other-site.com/payments/callSSL.php) to be accessed.

Put this header in your  http://my-other-site.com/payments/callSSL.php

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
```

for specific page

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://www.yourxmlrequestpage.php');
```

Hope this helps ,

thank you

Comment: Ok If you are concerned then replace * in the above with the page url from where you send xmlhttp request

Comment: The above edit will avoid security flaws. Let me know you status

Answer (score -1):

you need to add a var as xmlhttp; on starting to get the status result please use below code i modify it,

```
<script>
//Ajax to send request..
function sendPayment()
{
var xmlhttp;
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
      {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
      xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
      }
    else
      {// code for IE6, IE5
      xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
      }
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
          {
alert(xmlhttp.readyState);// this always returns = 1
alert(xmlhttp.responseText) ; //this is always empty.
          if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
            {
                if (xmlhttp.responseText=='1')
                {
                    alert('success');
                }   
            }
          }
    xmlhttp.open("POST","payments/callSSL.php",true);
    xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    xmlhttp.send(Id=100);
    return false;
}
</script>
```

Comment: same result.. No use.. i have used many ajax request where i have not all specified it as `var`

Comment: Add `xmlHttpRequest.send();` after  `xmlHttpRequest.onreadystatechange = processRequest;`. please try this may help you.

Comment: you please use with 'var xmlhttp;' hope this help or make sure it is processRequest function.