# How to retrieve data from JSON with javascript and jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, cors, jsonp

Ok so I have been trying to retrieve a single string in JSON from this website: 
http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/api/get_recent_summary/?count=1

This is the snippet I have:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Simple Page</title>
</head>
  <script src="jquery.js"></script>
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $.getJSON('http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/api/get_recent_summary/?count=1', function(data) 
        { 
            alert(data.title)
        });     
    });
    </script>
</html>
```

Just trying to get a simple title and display it as an alert or just write it on the website, for some reason I can't get it right. I also checked that my jquery is working so it can't be that.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Probably because there is no `title` attribute on the root JSON element, but on each element of the `posts` array

Comment: I would console.write(data) and see what's coming back, if anything. Might be Title instead of title or a JSON object not being returned.

Comment: This is what I get when I run the request: "XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/api/get_recent_summary/?count=1. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. " so you are just not authorized to read this resource, unless the server gives you permission

Comment: I remember using this json data for an app sometime ago, I don't understand why it wouldn't let me access it now.

Comment: Check if they provide JSONP http://learn.jquery.com/ajax/working-with-jsonp/

Comment: You have CORS issues, because the `Access-Control-Allow-origin:*` is not present in the response.

Comment: If you access the data from a server or an app this problem won't appear because it is only relevant to JavaScript executed in a Browser. That is why you can use the data without any problems from within your app. See https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-Origin_Resource_Sharing

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

CORS HTTP header is missing, so you can't do AJAX requests directly. You need to use server side proxy or use http://crossorigin.me/ service to fetch data from remote website.

Server you are accessing provides JSONP support, so you can convert it into JSONP call by adding `callback=?` to URL

```
$.getJSON('http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/api/get_recent_summary/?count=1&callback=?', function(data) 
{ 
    alert(data.posts[0].title)
});
```

In case if JSONP is not supported you can use crossorigin.me service, but I would not rely on this service for production use.

```
$.getJSON('http://crossorigin.me/http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/api/get_recent_summary/?count=1', function(data) 
        { 
            alert(data.posts[0].title)
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the Data that is returned from the provided endpoint your callback should read `alert(data.posts[0].title)`

Comment: That makes sense, but for some reason it still doesn't get anything.

Answer (score 0):

for this type of error you need to pass header param also with request check below links...

[How to allow CORS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7067966/how-to-allow-cors-in-express-node-js)
[Getting Cross Origin Block Request [CORS] error when using .getJSON to get Play Store App Details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23053349/getting-cross-origin-block-request-cors-error-when-using-getjson-to-get-play)