# CORS error on creating contact with google contacts api from localhost

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml, google-api, google-contacts-api

I get `Cross-Origin Request Blocked:` error on requesting with the below code.

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/default/full?access_token=' + token.access_token,
    type: 'POST',
    crossOrigin: true,
    crossDomain: true,
    Origin: 'http://localhost',
    Host: 'www.google.com',
    xhrFields: {
        withCredentials: true
        },
    dataType: 'xml',
    'Gdata-version': '3.0',
    'Content-Type': 'application/atom+xml',
    'body': xml,
    }).done(function(data) {
    console.log(data);
});

});
```

`GET` method retrieves contacts with jsonp(not for `POST` method) as datatype without any error but in `POST` method I get errors.

Comment: This will help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23053349/getting-cross-origin-block-request-cors-error-when-using-getjson-to-get-play?answertab=active#tab-top

Answer (score -1):

It's easy, you should set **server** **http response header** first. It's no business with your front-end javascript code. You need to return this header:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin:*
```

or

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin:your domain
```

Comment: google sends me response header so How can I set response headers?

Comment: please visit ::http://web.requestly.in/# to create a custom response header

Comment: FYI My browser is firefox