# Error when accessing localhost api in chrome net::ERR_INSECURE_RESPONSE

Tags: angularjs, google-chrome, angular-resource

I was trying to access api running in localhost using angular $resourses, chrome console gives me error saying ERR_INSECURE_RESPONSE.

I tried disabling web security in chrome. still same error. here is the angular factory that i used. How can I bypass this error and test my app.

```
    ImpactPortal.factory('apiFactory', function ($resource) {
    return $resource('https://localhost:8443/mifosng-provider/api/v1/client_impact_portal', {}, {
        query: {
            method: 'GET',
            params: {},
            isArray: true
        }
    })
});
```

Comment: What is the response you're trying to receive?

Comment: Are you using a valid SSL certificate, signed by a CA?

Comment: You have to implement SSL Certificate in your Web Server for your Project URL.

Comment: You can try `://localhost:8443/mifosng-provider/api/v1/client_impact_portal`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must authenticate first and then send each request along with the auth token.

I am using RestAngular so my settings might look a little different from what you are working on.

This will go in your application config :-

```
RestangularProvider.setDefaultHeaders({ 'X-Mifos-Platform-TenantId': 'default' });
```

and something like this will go in your controller/service

```
var login = Restangular.all('authentication?username=mifos&password=password').post().then(function(user) {
   console.log(user);
 }, function() {
  console.log("There was an error saving");
 });
```

Comment: Don't just pass the username and password in every request like that.. use a JWT or something else.

Answer (score 6):

Enabling CORS in Angular.js

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', [
    'myAppApiService']);

myApp.config(['$httpProvider', function($httpProvider) {
        $httpProvider.defaults.useXDomain = true;
        delete $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common['X-Requested-With'];
    }
]);
```

A server supporting CORS must respond to requests with several access control headers:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: "*"
```

By default, CORS requests are **not** made with cookies. If the server includes this header, then we
can send cookies along with our request by setting the withCredentials option to true.

```
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials (optional)
```

If we set the withCredentials option in our  request to true, but the server does not respond
with this header, then the request will fail and vice versa.

Answer (score 2):

Only try this:

Go to https://[your-domain].com and then chrome block you with the famous page:

> Your connection is not private

So go down to `ADVANVCED` and then `proceed`.

Your certificate is probably self-signed.

Remember to do that for each Chrome session.

Answer (score -2):

Error 501 (net::ERR_INSECURE_RESPONSE) - 501 Not Implemented 

The server either does not recognize the request method, or it lacks the ability to fulfill the request. Usually this implies future availability (e.g., a new feature of a web-service API).

Can you confirm that curl request is working fine

```
curl -k --user damien@email.com:password https://localhost:8443/mifosng-provider/api/v1/client_impact_portal
```

If it is working fine:

```
ImpactPortal.factory('apiFactory', function ($resource) {
    return $resource('https://localhost:8443/mifosng-provider/api/v1/client_impact_portal', {}, {
        query: {
            method: 'JSONP',
            params: {},
            isArray: true
        }
    })
});
```

Try following this tutorial that consume an external API: http://www.toptal.com/angular-js/a-step-by-step-guide-to-your-first-angularjs-app

Comment: thanks for the detailed reply. But my problem is that when using localhost api only. it works fine with urls mentioned in that tutorial.
firefox gives an error saying "Cross-Origin Request Blocked: This can be fixed by moving the resource to the same domain or enabling CORS."

Comment: CORS is blocked in browser side that won't allow AJAX to request data from another domain. You can add crossdomain.xml like this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20442628/cors-jquery-ajax-request or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/213251/can-someone-post-a-well-formed-crossdomain-xml-sample

Or the workaround for AJAX Cross-Domain is JSONP: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3506208/jquery-ajax-cross-domain but the API should support this kind of request.