# How to call web api from an https web site?

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-web-api

I have a web site which is served over an https protocol. This is written in angularJs. The Website is calling an asp.net web api service over http, and then I'm getting this error:

> angular.js:10765 Mixed Content: The page at 'https://example.com/forms/#/question-set-4#topOfThePage' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure XMLHttpRequest endpoint 'http://webapiaddress/api/ControllerName/GenerateCaptcha'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.(anonymous function) @ angular.js:10765r @ angular.js:10558g @ angular.js:10268(anonymous function) @ angular.js:14792$eval @ angular.js:16052$digest @ angular.js:15870$apply @ angular.js:16160g @ angular.js:10589T @ angular.js:10787w.onload @ angular.js:10728
>   angular.js:10765 XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://webapiaddres/api/SomeController/GenerateCaptcha. Failed to start loading.

So the error suggests for me that I should serve the web api self host over an https addres. So in the config of that web api self host I'm changing it to https//webapiaddres/

But then I'm getting this:

> angular.js:10765 GET
>   https:/webapiaddress/api/SomeController/GenerateCaptcha
>   net::ERR_INSECURE_RESPONSE

What am I doing wrong? Why is this happening. Strange thing is that that this does not scream that I don't have CORS enabled, but this could be because of the fact that this web api selfhost and the site is on the same server. I can't find any simmilar problem to mine in google.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error when accessing localhost api in chrome net::ERR\_INSECURE\_RESPONSE](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24598187/error-when-accessing-localhost-api-in-chrome-neterr-insecure-response)

Comment: Sorry but I don't think this is it. From what it looks like that post states that someone is trying to call service via https, that is something is served over https protocol. My issue is the other way around

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to solve the problem with my colleage and it was very simple. It did not came up at first glance. I've ran the address of the web api in the chrome browser and there there was an request for accepting an certificate. When I did that everything went smooth. This is the work for our administrator not from the code, but this was quite interesting experience.